# Change Request URI in Filter Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, requestdispatcher

I've used a `Request Dispatcher` in a Filter to change the request URI, but the problem with this Request Dispatcher is that it breaks the Filter chain. So, the Filter which is going to be called after this Filter doesn't get called.

If I use send redirect then the Filter will be called but the URL is reflected in the browser.

I then tried the `HttpRequestWrapper` class to change the URI by overriding the `getRequestURI()` method and I've written the whole logic to change the URI and return it. This method gets called and the URL is indeed changed.

However, Tomcat always throws an HTTP 404 Error. I've also tried with GlassFish.

I don't know what the problem is. Is overriding the `getRequestURI()` the right thing to do?